# unable to get the content when language is changed from default language

Tags: typo3

i am new in typo3. i am facing problem with language. i have made a page name as footer and set content in both of my languages i.e de,en.

```
lib.content_from_page3 = COA
lib.content_from_page3 {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select.where = colPos = 0
        select.pidInList = 48
    }
}
lib.content_from_page4 = COA
lib.content_from_page4 {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select.where = colPos = 0
        select.pidInList = 52
    }
}
```

This is my typoscript that is set in template. and

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content_from_page3" />

<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content_from_page4" />
```

this is code of accessing the data. lib.content_from_page3 is content that is default language and lib.content_from_page4is in english language.

problem is that when default language is selected everything is fine but when english is selected there is no data

#### is any one who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have already made language configuration properly  like below

```
# Localization:
config {
    linkVars = L(int)
    sys_language_uid = 0
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    language = en
    locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="en" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config {
            sys_language_uid = 1
            language = de
            locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
            htmlTag_setParams = lang="de" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }
[global]
```

May This object can helps you

```
lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
  colPos.cObject = TEXT
  colPos.cObject {
     field = colPos
     ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
     ifEmpty.cObject {
        value.current = 1
        ifEmpty = 0
     }
  }
  pageUid.cObject = TEXT
  pageUid.cObject {
     field = pageUid
     ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
  }
  contentFromPid.cObject = TEXT
  contentFromPid.cObject {
     data = DB:pages:{register:pageUid}:content_from_pid
     data.insertData = 1
  }
  wrap.cObject = TEXT
  wrap.cObject {
     field = wrap
  }
}
20 = CONTENT
20 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
     includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
     orderBy = sorting
     where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
     where.insertData = 1
     pidInList.data = register:pageUid
     pidInList.override.data = register:contentFromPid
  }
  stdWrap {
     dataWrap = {register:wrap}
     required = 1
  }
}
30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

and put this in your template file

```
< f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0',pageUid:'52'}" />
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0',pageUid:'48'}" />
```

If an above object can not help you then please try below the object

```
lib.content_from_page3 = COA
lib.content_from_page3 {
10 = CONTENT
10 {
 table = tt_content

select {

    pidInList = {$config.logopageId}

    where = colPos = 0 

    max = 1

    languageField = sys_language_uid

}
}
}
```

Let me know know if you need any help!!

Welcome in TYPO3!:)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. i have fixed the error. the error is i am not choosing the default language in language tab when editing a content in english language.   I want to ask one more question. how to make an eCommerce website in typo3 and how to integrate extensions?

Comment: It will depend on your requirement,you can https://www.typo3multishop.com/, https://aimeos.org/typo3-shop-extension/,https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/quick_shop/, tt_product but if you want same like woocommerce , it will not possible.

Comment: i need help again. how to make an ajax request in typo3??

Comment: you have to create a custom page typeNum like this and use it as URL

Comment: sorry didn't get it. Could you please explain. i want a registration page so i need to make an ajax request to php file so that i can process some work on the data

Comment: You can get the idea from here https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/detail/building-an-typo3-extension-with-ajax-call/